# Eclipse: prevent * insertion after new lines in Javadoc comments

Tags: eclipse

When typing new Javadoc comments for methods in (Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0)) on pressing enter at the end of the first line, it auto-formats from ...

```
/** some docs here
```

... to ...

```
/** some docs here
 * 
 */
```

This is not our house style.  We don't include the extra * on every line, just the start and end delimiters.

Can this be turned off?  I've turned off everything relating to comments and formatting that I can find and it is still doing it.

In Preferences:

- In Java, Code Style, Formatter (for the active profile) I have everything turned off.
- In Java, Code Templates, I've tried editing or blanking out all of the templates.
- In Java, Editor, Typing, turning off 'Javadoc and region comments' stops the trailing */ being added, but not the leading * on each new line.

Our house style is:

```
/** some does here
    */
```

(Long story short, this is an extremely efficient style when doing a lot of editing of Javadocs.)

Comment: What do you expect pressing Enter inside a Javadoc comment to do? What do multi-line Javadoc comments look like in your house style?

Comment: @howlger I've updated the question to include the style.  What I don't want is for Eclipse to assume I want a left-margin made of * all the way down the Javadoc (in the source).  Yet it always inserts this leading star when hitting enter.